# How can I forward specific domain look-up queries if record not found in the local zone file?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

We have our DNS records in godaddy.com and an internal DNS server configured in our LAN.

I want to configure the zone file of the domain such that if the record is not found in the the local zone file it should do a look-up in the public DNS server.

Is it possible using bind 9.3 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is good practice to use a separate zone for your internal network.  If you do that, then you can just forward your requests off to your forwarders or forward directly to GoDaddy.

Doing split configuration of a zone is difficult when using two different providers.  It may be simpler to just copy the few entries in from GoDaddy.  You may find you want to use internal addresses rather than external addresses for your servers.

If you are allowing DHCP to update your DNS it is more important to use a separate zone.  Otherwise users can replace the entries for your servers.